# Number of days since 01/01/0001 to any given date

Tags: java, math

Is there a mathematical formula to account for the total number of days from 01/01/0001 to any given date. I have one that accounts for the total number of days from 01/01/0001 to the any given year. But I don't know how to account when you have days and months after. If that makes any sense.

This is the formula to account for a given year:

```
totalDays = (year-1)*365 + (year-1)/4 - (year-1)/100 + (year-1)/400;
```

Comment: "*This is the formula to account for a given year totalDays = (year-1)*365 + (year-1)/4 - (year-1)/100 + (year-1)/400;*" - [I can guarantee you that this formula is wrong.](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/51370/why-our-calendars-skipped-11-days-1752)

Comment: which calendar are we using for 01/01/0001?

Comment: Why? Java comes with nice date/time APIs that can do this for you.

Comment: Hey this is for an assignment and i'm expected to solve it using a mathematical formular. Then i just find the modulus and assign the different possible answers to the different days of the week. Basically, my code is supposed to accept a date and return what day that date is.

Comment: Look at this [Wikipedia page on Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) for some good ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the number of days since Jan 1 of year 1, or the day of the week of a given date? These are two very different problems